# True or not: $~f:[0,3] \to \mathbb R~$ can never be surjective

Tags: calculus

True or not: $~f:[0,3] \to \mathbb R~$ can never be surjective

Is the $~f~$ continuous? And if its an closed interval that means it has a fixed point in $~0~$ and $~3~$, so it can't be surjective, because the domain only transforms into a sub category of $~\mathbb R~$?

Comment: There exists a function $f$ such that $f([0,3])=\mathbb{R}$ but it can't be a continuous one.

Comment: Hello. Please consider formatting your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Since $[0,3]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality, there exist a lot of bijections between them. Continuity is an obstruction to surjectivity, since continuous functions preserve compactness.

Answer (score 2):

Without continuity $f$ can be surjective. In fact there is a bijection from $[0,3]$ onto $\mathbb R$. If $f$ is continuous then the range has to be compact and $\mathbb R$ is not compact. So $f$ cannot be surjective.

The answer to the question in the title is: FALSE, $f$ can be surjective.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain further, so a function on a closed interval is always continous( expect if it is stated otherwise in the domain)? can f:[ 0,3] be not continous?

Comment: @sasaako I have added a line to may answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a bijection between the intervals $[a,b]$, $a<b$, and $[0,1]$.

There is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

There is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto \tan(\pi x-\pi/2)$.

The composition of bijections is again a bijection. Thus the composition gives the requested answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So a function with a domain on a closed interval with its codomain being R can never be surjective?